# Application on ipod Touch 5g does not use full resolution ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.height == 480.0)

Tags: ios, screen, resolution

We have an application which uses the full resolution of the iphone 5 and works so far perfectly. Now we got a complaint from a tester that it does not work on the ipod Touch 5g.

Surprisingly the log shows that [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds returns (320.0, 480.0) on
the ipod Touch while on the iphone 5 it shows the correct bounds (320.0, 568.0) ?!

After this I investigated and it seems that the iOS looks up if an image with "-568h" suffix exists and decides to run either in letterbox mode (320,480) or with full resolution
(320,568).

Now I have a nasty suspicion:
The name of our high-res splashscreen image is Default~iphone-568h@2x.png which accordingly to Apple should work (We have an universal app running on both ipad and iphone).

As I have no ipod touch here yet, can someone confirm this suspicion:

- Default~iphone-568h@2x.png works on iphone 5, but not on ipod touch 5g
- Default-568h@2x.png works on both devices.

EDIT: 8-0 I do not believe this. I have now an ipod Touch available and an iphone 5.
As indicated, I am using the ~iphone modifier for the other images to differentiate between ipad and iphone.

Renaming the Default~iphone-568h@2x.png to Default-568h@2x.png now works on ipod touch 5, but not on the iphone 5 anymore. It is *exactly* reversed !!

Replication:

- Use an universal app for all devices (iphone/ipad retina/non-retina/4")
- Name the "~iphone" identifier for iphone/ipod and nothing for ipad
- Use either Default~iphone-568h@2x.png or Default-568h@2x.png and look if it runs with the correct full resolution on *both* iphone 5 and iphone touch 5.

Can please someone confirm this ? Xcode 4.5.2 / iOS SDK 6.0

EDIT 2: rckoenes answer did the trick, but still I am disappointed that the purported device identifier for iphones does not work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Default~iphone-568h@2x.png` is not correct this should be  `Default-568h@2x.png`. Don't use the `~iphone` modifier on the launch images, the `~iphone` or `~ipad` modifier is only useful if you need a specific image of view load on different devices. Thus it is not needed for the launch image.

You can find this in the [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH1-SW1) section about the [App Launch (Default) Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12).

My Universal app has the follwoing images:

- Default.png
- Default@2x.png
- Default-568h@2x.png
- Default-Portrait~ipad.png
- Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
- Default-Landscape~ipad.png
- Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png

Comment: Yes, it *is* used for different devices. It is an universal app, so we need th modifier.

Comment: You will not need the device modifier for the `Default-568h@2x.png` since it is only used by the 4" device (iPhone and iPod Touch)

Comment: I've just checked and on my iPhone 5 with an universal app. And it does work without the `~iphone` modifier. Besure to clean you build and remove the app from you device before trying to run the app on the device again.

Comment: That did it. But still it is very strange behavior.

Comment: Well yes, I only use the device modifier for iPad only, this way I'm sure it will work on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Device modifier must be at the end of file name http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html

So correct name of file is Default-568h@2x~iphone.png

Comment: This is incorrect, you do not neet the `~iphone` modifier for this launch images.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation is not correct in this case. Xcode 4 did not accept the "correct" order, but only the name I have given. :(

Comment: Xcode doesn't accept, but iOS does. Anyway Default-568h@2x.png works perfect on all devices.